# Changing facebook tab icon

Tags: facebook, iframe, icons

thanks in advance for your help. I have a custom facebook tab which is set up as an iFrame, it needs to have a custom icon but despite setting the icon in various places it refuses to show up correctly on my main page. Here is what it look likes now

[image]

I have changed it in the developer page by setting the box and the change icon option but it never shows up on my main page

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i'm missing?

Thanks, all help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the icon you are using is in correct resolution, if the resolution is high, then the icon will not display. This also happens on normal websites.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your description, you have assigned the icon correctly. Looks like a Facebook bug or caching issue to me. Have you tried renaming your image file and re-assigning it?

Comment: I just tried renaming and reuploading the icon, I cleared my browser cache but still no change. Any more suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I can only think of creating a new app with the correct icon.

Answer (score 0):

Remove app from the page and then add it again :)