# Facebook Page Tab App - update dropdown Icon

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to update the Facebook Page Tab App Icon that you see in the on the Tab Page and the dropdown for Apps. I know it's possible to update the main Thumbnail with the API calls here 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs, but updating the **custom_image_url** does not update he dropdown icon.
Here is screenshot:[image]

I found a simular question here - [Changing facebook tab icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318817/changing-facebook-tab-icon), but I am looking for an API solution.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to update Page tab icon via API (same goes for Application icon).

Actually the icon used for that is Application icon and it's the same for all pages application installed to, so you cannot change it for specific page but the whole application.

Comment: thanks, do you know if there is a way to update it on App level using the facebook API